# How to know if a table scroll bar reached the end in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Check out this fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/wzwaj0k0/1/

I want to trigger the alert when scrollbar reaches the end but not able to

JS

```
function GetScrollerEndPoint()
{
   var scrollHeight = $("#Mytable").prop('scrollHeight');
   var divHeight = $("#Mytable").height();
   var scrollerEndPoint = scrollHeight - divHeight;

   var divScrollerTop =  $("#Mytable").scrollTop();
   if(divScrollerTop === scrollerEndPoint)
   {
       alert("you reached the end");
   }
}
```

CSS

```
table {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table.GeneratedTable thead {
  background-color: #959595;
}
```

HTML

```
<table id="Mytable" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

tried everything . but its should only be that table , because i tried with window.scroll function its working but i have to add rows through ajax to this table . so need to go to the function when only table scrollbar reaches the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery have `.scroll` event you can add to your table.

#### get the inner height of your table.

```
  var maxScrollHeight = $('#Mytable tbody').height() + $('#Mytable thead').height();
```

#### get the scrollTop height + table height (100px as you set in CSS)

```
  var scrollFromTop = Math.ceil($('#Mytable').scrollTop()) + $('#Mytable').height();
```

using `Math.ceil()` since scrollTop() at Stackoverflow return a little less than normal.
(jsfiddle works fine) https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/5d219rmh/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#Mytable').scroll(function() {

    var maxScrollHeight = $('#Mytable tbody').height() + $('#Mytable thead').height();
    var scrollFromTop = Math.ceil($('#Mytable').scrollTop()) + $('#Mytable').height();

    if (scrollFromTop == maxScrollHeight) {
      alert("you reached the end");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
table {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table.GeneratedTable thead {
  background-color: #959595;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are never calling **GetScrollerEndPoint**. One option is to add an **onscroll** event to your table.

```
<table id="Mytable" onscroll="GetScrollerEndPoint()">
    ...
</table>
```

This should work even if you add new rows to the table. Also **GetScrollerEndPoint** will only get called when scrolling the table.

Here you have an example.

```js
function GetScrollerEndPoint()
{
   var scrollHeight = $("#Mytable").prop('scrollHeight');
   var divHeight = $("#Mytable").height();
   var scrollerEndPoint = scrollHeight - divHeight;
   
   var divScrollerTop =  $("#Mytable").scrollTop();
   if(divScrollerTop === scrollerEndPoint)
   {
       alert("you reached the end");
   }
}
```

```css
table {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table.GeneratedTable thead {
  background-color: #959595;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="Mytable" onscroll="GetScrollerEndPoint()">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr> <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```